# How to draw a line between two points in opencv c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, line, point

```
  Point p1(faces[i].x + (eyes[j].x +  eyes[j].width*0.5), faces[i].y + (eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5));
  Point p2(faces[i].x + (eyes[j].x +  eyes[j].width*0.5), faces[i].y + (eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5));
  line(frame, p1, p2, Scalar( 255, 255, 0 ), 5, 8, 0);
```

This is the code I had wrote to draw a line segment between the two points p1 and p2. Actually I am getting the display of points, but no line segment. Can anybody help me!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just guessing... if the points are positioned in the same spot, you have a point not a line.

Comment: p1 and p2 seem identical ?

Comment: Actually I need to draw line between two centers of eyes. Tats y I took both centers. I did detecting of eyes from face.

Comment: I use haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses to detect eyes. After detecting eyes, got centers of eyes. Now need to join these centers with line.

Answer (score 2):

With the code provided above one can deduce that the two points are located in **the same place** thus you're not getting any line but rather a point.

Also take a look at the line function: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line

By the way: there's a problem with your indices. If you're trying to link two eyes' centers you should rather do something like

```
Point p1(faces[0].x + (eyes[0].x +  eyes[0].width*0.5), faces[0].y + (eyes[0].y + eyes[0].height*0.5));
Point p2(faces[0].x + (eyes[1].x +  eyes[1].width*0.5), faces[0].y + (eyes[1].y + eyes[1].height*0.5));
```

assuming faces[0] points to the coordinates of a squared face, eyes[0] is the first eye on that face and eyes[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNeX1.jpg) is the second eye (and assuming that the following doesn't happen)

[image]

Comment: I need to get the center point of two centers of eyes. Can you suggest me the solution!!

Comment: I am running it in a loop, image is also fluctuating in a video. How come i do this.

Comment: You need to figure out what are those indices "i" and "j" and how to use them. I can't help more with the limited info available.